# getting CORS errors for apparently no real reson when calling spring boot backend from angular frontend

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

I have this CORS configuration in a spring boot controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4201", "http://127.0.0.1:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4201", "127.0.0.1:4200"}, allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

and I'm calling it from this origin:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4200/some route
```

why am I still getting these errors:

```
[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected! polyfills.js:6494:28
[webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect... polyfills.js:6494:28
[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled. index.js:551:21
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode. core.mjs:25520:16
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/settings/navbar. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 302.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/settings/navbar. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/settings/navbar", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8080/settings/navbar: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
core.mjs:9171:22
```

[edit]
I tried using an extension that allows CORS and now get this error:

```
Error: 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://127.0.0.1:8080/login", error: {…} }
​
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="author" content="">\n    <title>Please sign in</title>\n    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">\n    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n     <div class="container">\n      <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">\n        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>\n        <p>\n          <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>\n          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>\n        </p>\n        <p>\n          <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>\n          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>\n        </p>\n<input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="5ikzj15swYb-YzUEXCdaMwM1L9zztCsaCrhbiYGbIG0qUBNlgkoFvzoJ-bbTVQNgawpuVWFQAuTCh043bo5j6OL_EAxMNXJW" />\n        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>\n      </form>\n</div>\n</body></html>' }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit() }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://127.0.0.1:8080/login"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
navbar.component.ts:31:14
```

I have no idea why I'm getting an error for a /login route and why my browser / frontend is even calling it, I checked my hosts file which looks like this:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.0.224 host.docker.internal
192.168.0.224 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I don't know how to solve this issue